# Match string in REQUEST_URI and redirect to that match

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect the old URL /bakery/pie?id=55 or /bakery/cake?id=433 to /bakery/pie or /bakery/cake. I tried to redirect on match but I'm error log shows "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects"

This is running on WordPress.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{$REQUEST_URI} (pie|cake) [NC]
RewriteRule . /bakery/%1? [R,L]
```

What is wrong with the above configuration?

Answer (score 1):

This finally gave me the result I was looking for and works with WordPress:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (cake|pie.*|des.*) [NC]
RewriteRule . /bakery/%1? [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

`%{$REQUEST_URI}` is not correct variable it is `%{REQUEST_URI}`. Also you must check `QUERY_STRING` condition.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=\d+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^bakery/(pie|cake)/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, however, this does not work for me. The page is not redirecting to /bakery/cake or /pie and I'm not seeing any errors in the error log.

Comment: In WP .htaccess make sure this rule is right below `RewriteEngine On` line